# Python-changing color of buttons

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am here today to ask some help on this task. I need to make my buttons to change its color depending on the value of the variable "color" so if in this:

```
M = [
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2]
    ]
```

If hi find (0,0) the button must be white but it doesn't make any change so please help me.

```
boton1 = Button(jugar, bg = color)
boton1.place(x=50,y=10)
boton1.config(heigh=2,width=5)

def cambia_colores(M):
    n=len(M)
    m=len(M[0])
    if M != []:
        return cambia_colores_aux(M,n,m,0,0)
    else:
        return "Error"
def cambia_colores_aux(M,n,m,i,j):
    global color
    if j == m:
        return color
    elif M[i][j] == 0:
        color = "blue"

    elif M[i][j] == 1 :
        color = "black"

    elif M[i][j] == 2:
       color = "red"

    else:
        return cambia_colores_aux(M,n,m,i,j+1)   
    jugar.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you indicate in tags what GUI you are using ?, in many you have to explictly change the Button colour with boton1['bg']= newcolor. the logic is strange, why does only j change, why is i always 0 ?

Comment: Are you really calling `jugar.mainloop()` inside the `cambia_colores_aux` function? That is highly unusual. Usually you call mainloop as the last line of code in your main logic. Is this just an indentation typographical error?

Comment: yes, that was a typo error, and i'm using tkinter, i'm triying to change the colors of the button using the values inside "M", i made this changes: 
    def cambia_colores(M):
    global color
    n=len(M)
    m=len(M[0]
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,m):
            if M[i][j] == 0:
                color = "blue"
    
            elif M[i][j] == 1 :
                color = "black"
       
            elif M[i][j] == 2:
                color = "red"
    
    
cambia_colores(M)

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of a widget you must call the `configure` method. You can't just change a variable that you used when creating the widget.

For example:

```
...
new_color = cambia_colores(...)
boton1.configure(background=new_color)
...
```

Comment: i made a iterative version of that, i'm using tkinter for the gui, moved the jugar.mainloop(), but now just change one button, and the others takes the same color